# Does Quasi-increasing and Quasi-decreasing imply continuity?

Tags: analysis, limits, continuity

Suppose $f$ is a function $f$: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Then Do the following equations imply the continuity of $f$ at $s$?

$ \lim_{x\uparrow s} \sup f(x) \leq f(s) \leq \lim_{x\downarrow s} \inf f(x)$

$ \lim_{x\uparrow s} \inf f(x) \geq f(s) \geq \lim_{x\downarrow s} \sup f(x)$

Answer (score 3):

I am supposing that $\lim_{x \uparrow s} g(x)$ is "the limit as $x$ approaches $s$ from the left" or equivalently as $x < s$ is taken to $s$. [and I suppose the similar natural object for $\lim_{x \downarrow s}$, implying that this limit is taken over $x > s$].

If that's right, then the answer is no.

Consider the function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & x \leq 0 \text{ and } x \not \in \mathbb{Q} \\
0 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
1 & x \geq 0 \text{ and } x \not \in \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

Now we look at the continuity of $f$ at $0$. It is clearly true that $\lim_{x\uparrow 0} \sup f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} \inf f(x) = 0$. But $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Sorry I guess I just gave the wrong definition of quasi-increasing(decreasing). How about now?